# Remove objects within array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, object

I need to remove all the objects within array who meet the conditions i will show down below. I'll let here the documents and an example of what i've done.

```
//document 1
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec73abebd7e4d618a057350"),
    "code" : "X20",
    "title" : "Full stack developer",
    "location" : "Paris",
    "date" : ISODate("2020-05-22T02:36:46.272Z"),
    "candidates" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "David",
            "last_name" : "Broncano",
            "telephone" : "642025552",
            "email" : "david@gmail.com"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Pablo",
            "last_name" : "Claros",
            "telephone" : "628721784",
            "email" : "pablo@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}

// document 2
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4ec73abebd7e4d618a057350"),
    "code" : "X50",
    "title" : "Full stack developer",
    "location" : "Madrid",
    "date" : ISODate("2020-05-22T02:36:46.272Z"),
    "candidates" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Maria",
            "last_name" : "Mars",
            "telephone" : "642024582",
            "email" : "dasd@gmail.com"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Pablo",
            "last_name" : "Claros",
            "telephone" : "628721784",
            "email" : "pablo@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

So i need to remove all the candidates where location is Madrid.I have done this but it removes the field. Is it possible to just remove the content of it using $pull or something?

```
db.offers.update(
                      { location : "Madrid"},
                      { 
   $unset:{
      "candidates":""
   }   } , 
                      { 
                          multi : true 
                      }
                     )
```

Comment: You can to use the [$pull update operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/index.html#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents) to remove specific nested documents based on a condition.

Comment: Yes but i don't know how to put it here because the condition is not inside the array as u can see. I can not put $pull: candidates : name :"x" or anything similar because it wouldn't do what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding, you need to just clear the `candidates` array and maintain that as `candidates: []`. For this, you can use use `$set` operator to set `candidates` to `[]` based on your condition

```js
db.offers.update({ location : "Madrid"}, { $set:{ "candidates": [] } } , { multi : true })
```